# FindName does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, findname

My `FindName` does not work, the value is null.
And I can't call my `x:Name="QuantiteTextBox"` in my code-behind...
The name seems to not exist in this context..

XAML :

```
<GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Nb">
     <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <TextBox x:Name="QuantiteTextBox" Text="{Binding Quantite, ElementName=EditTableUserControl}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="-10,0,0,0"/>
          </DataTemplate>
     </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

WPF :

```
var quantiteTextBox = (TextBox)FindName("QuantiteTextBox");
```

How can I resolve this problem please ? Thanks.

Comment: You sure you are using FindName on the right window?

Comment: Solution :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type/1759923#1759923 An alternative to the FindName.

Answer (score 1):

FindName won't work because the TextBox is in a template.  That <TextBox> declaration isn't actually creating a TextBox named "QuantiteTextBox."  Instead, GridViewColumn uses that TextBox as a template to create more TextBoxes.  Imagine if that GridViewColumn was in a GridView with 10 rows.  You might get 10 TextBox instances, so there is no single TextBox with that name.

When you call FindName, it queries a certain scope.  If the code you posted is right inside a WPF Window, then it will look for controls inside that window only.  Since that TextBox isn't in the window, you won't find it.

At this point, I don't know if you meant to find one of the TextBoxes in the Window, or if you really want the one in the control template.  Take a look at t

See [Why doesnt Window.FindName() discover the x:Name of a button in a child UserControl? AKA how do NameScopes work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764364/) for a better explanation than I can give.  In short: You probably want to do this another way.